# Video display is garbled when recording on Galaxy S3

Tags: android, android-camera, galaxy, android-mediarecorder

I'm writing a camera app and am having an issue with the S3. Whenever I start recording, the display goes to garbage (see screenshots below). Then, when I stop recording I get an exception:

```
10-02 13:36:31.647: E/MediaRecorder(24283): stop failed: -1007
10-02 13:36:31.647: D/AndroidRuntime(24283): Shutting down VM
10-02 13:36:31.647: W/dalvikvm(24283): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c49a68)
10-02 13:36:31.647: E/AndroidRuntime(24283): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-02 13:36:31.647: E/AndroidRuntime(24283): java.lang.RuntimeException: stop failed.
10-02 13:36:31.647: E/AndroidRuntime(24283):    at android.media.MediaRecorder.native_stop(Native Method)
10-02 13:36:31.647: E/AndroidRuntime(24283):    at android.media.MediaRecorder.stop(MediaRecorder.java:742)
10-02 13:36:31.647: E/AndroidRuntime(24283):    at com.myapp.android.ui.camera.NewCameraActivity.stopRecording(NewCameraActivity.java:178)
10-02 13:36:31.647: E/AndroidRuntime(24283):    at com.myapp.android.ui.camera.NewCameraActivity.toggleRecording(NewCameraActivity.java:189)
10-02 13:36:31.647: E/AndroidRuntime(24283):    at com.myapp.android.ui.camera.NewCameraActivity.onClick(NewCameraActivity.java:97)
10-02 13:36:31.647: E/AndroidRuntime(24283):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3565)
10-02 13:36:31.647: E/AndroidRuntime(24283):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14165)
10-02 13:36:31.647: E/AndroidRuntime(24283):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
10-02 13:36:31.647: E/AndroidRuntime(24283):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-02 13:36:31.647: E/AndroidRuntime(24283):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-02 13:36:31.647: E/AndroidRuntime(24283):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
10-02 13:36:31.647: E/AndroidRuntime(24283):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-02 13:36:31.647: E/AndroidRuntime(24283):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-02 13:36:31.647: E/AndroidRuntime(24283):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
10-02 13:36:31.647: E/AndroidRuntime(24283):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
10-02 13:36:31.647: E/AndroidRuntime(24283):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I've tested my app on the Galaxy Nexus (4.1), Galaxy S2, Nexus S, and Galaxy Tab 10.1. All of them work fine. I've followed [development guidelines for video recording](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#capture-video). I don't understand why this device is so different from the others. Here's what I'm seeing on the device. First picture is before I start recording. Second picture is what happens once I start recording.

[image: Before I've started recording]

[image: After I start recording]

Here's my code for preparing and starting the `MediaRecorder` object:

```
@Override
public void onClick( View v ) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.camera_action_ImageView:
            int mode = getMode();
            if ( mode == MODE_PHOTO ) {
                focusThenTakePicture();
            }
            else if ( mode == MODE_VIDEO ) {
                toggleRecording();
            }
            break;
    }
}

private void startRecording() {

    if ( prepareRecorder() ) {
        getRecorder().start();
        setRecording( true );
    }
}

@TargetApi( 9 )
private boolean prepareRecorder() {

    Camera camera = getCamera();
    camera.unlock();

    MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    setRecorder( recorder );
    recorder.setCamera( camera );
    recorder.setAudioSource( MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER );
    recorder.setVideoSource( MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA );

    CamcorderProfile profile;
    if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD ) {
        profile = CamcorderProfile.get( CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH );
    }
    else {
        profile = CamcorderProfile.get( getCameraId(), CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH );
    }
    recorder.setProfile( profile );

    File outputFile = LocalMediaUtil.getOutputMediaFile( LocalMediaUtil.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO );
    setRecorderOutputFile( outputFile );
    recorder.setOutputFile( outputFile.toString() );
    recorder.setPreviewDisplay( getPreview().getHolder().getSurface() );

    try {
        recorder.prepare();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        camera.lock();
        setRecorder( null );
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

private void stopRecording() {

    MediaRecorder recorder = getRecorder();
    recorder.stop();
    releaseRecorder();
    setRecording( false );

    LocalMediaUtil.scanMedia( this, getRecorderOutputFile().toString(), 90 );
    setRecorderOutputFile( null );
}

private void toggleRecording() {

    if ( isRecording() ) {
        stopRecording();
    }
    else {
        startRecording();
    }
}

private void releaseRecorder() {

    MediaRecorder recorder = getRecorder();
    if ( recorder != null ) {

        recorder.reset();
        recorder.release();
        setRecorder( null );

        getCamera().lock();
    }
}
```

**Edit:** So this has something to do with the `CamcorderProfile` being set. I change it to `CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW` and it worked fine. So how can I have high resolution video without garbled output?

**Edit2:** So with `CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW` set, I get no errors using the video recorder. However, the output video looks very similar the garbled screenshot posted above. So what gives?

Comment: sell it as iOS6-map-like camera app

Comment: Google bug report: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38139&thanks=38139&ts=1349306102

Comment: @JasonRobinson Why did they close the bug report? Could've at least point you in another direction or something. That's just lazy.

Comment: @ShadowScripter Yeah I don't think they read the description or something. He thought I was asking for user support :-\. I asked this question during the last (10-3) Android Developer Office Hours and they instructed me to open a bug report.

Comment: I think google cannot fix the twisted implementation of Samsung. A lot, if not all, samsung devices requires a particular, non standard, non documented (at least in english) procedure to do one thing or another with the camera. Galaxy K: no way to have functional front cam (output similar to this issue); Galaxy Note: can't shoot with "High Quality" profile; Galaxy S2: requires specific "set parameter" calls to get full resolution working... If you did not get my point: you should talk to samsung mobile instead of google. (and if they reply something useful, let the whole world know the link!)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had a similar problem, and finally figured out it was due to sharing the preview surface between the camera and the media recorder (I'm not sure this is actually the underlying cause, but from the API calls it appears that way).

I'm assuming you have already opened the camera and attached a preview display to it, if so try inserting the following lines at the top of your prepareRecorder method:

```
Camera camera = getCamera();
camera.stopPreview();
camera.lock();
camera.release();

camera = Camera.open();
camera.unlock();
```

You might also need to reassign the camera local to the field hidden behind getCamera(), unfortunately I can't tell how you've implemented it with the given code snippet.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome! Works great on Huawei U8800 with custom ICS.

Comment: This problem is associated with setPreviewSize. If your recording frame sizes doesn't match with preview sizes. it shows a garbage preview on few devices.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with an Samsung Note. My problem was that the preview was set in a resolution, and the recording was set in another bigger resolution (resolution which was not supported by my phone), and this is why it looked like that. You should try:

`recorder.setVideoSize(320, 240);`

If it works, then it means your initial resolution was not supported/

Answer (score 0):

This is because preview resolution and Mediarecorder resolutions are different (and they can be different depending on the device, but on some devices it seems to cause an issue).

Check the Android camera app, it does not stop the preview and then start recording (you can check this by keeping the flash on, if you stop the preview and then start recording the flash will turn off and then on again, whereas in the Android camera app that does not happen).

The "accepted" answer here only works because the camera releases the preview surface and mediarecorder can then adjust the resolution to one of the mediarecorder resolutions, but it is not technically correct.

Comment: Further investigation into this issue makes the whole issue more complex. It's not just a matching of resolution but at the driver level certain preview resolutions don't seem to properly honor what appears to be the same aspect or zoom level as the same recording resolution. This can result in an adjustment of distortion or apparent change of "zoom level" when pressing record. Stopping the preview as suggested by Stuart Ervine does work but I still think it's a work around rather than proper solution.

Comment: Great to see the real reason this occurs uncovered... do you have a code example of a proper solution? It'd be great to not have to stop and start the camera!